# Como se cuando un formulario "guarda" o solo "retorna" al accionar un "Submit" JAVASCRIPT o JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, base-de-datos, formularios

Especifico: Tengo un formulario en Laravel, guarda en base de datos (por ahora en localhost - xampp), con su modelo, controlador (php), archivo js (javascript), con plantillas blade (html), y sus respectivas "Validaciones Laravel" (esta 100% funcional).

Verán, Cuando le doy guardar al formulario y esta todo lleno, funciona, guarda en su respectiva tabla en base de datos, etc. Cuando le doy guardar pero con un campo vacío, retorna el formulario pero con el mensaje de error en su respectivo campo y no guarda nada en la base de datos.
Quiero saber como detectar cuando guarda en la base de datos y cuando no, específicamente por que quiero hacerle una "condicional", `if`, "hacer tal acción, solo cuando guarde en la base de datos", no cuando retorne los errores de validación, ya que al investigar y usar la funcion `Submit()` o
`$( "form" ).submit(function () {`, no funciona ya que cuando se le da clic al botón "Guardar" (que es submit obvio) ejecuta la función/acción, guarde o no guarde en la base de datos

Ejemplos de algunas funciones que llegue a hacer:

```
$("#idDelBoton").click(function () {
    if ($("form").submit()) {
        //aqui codigo/accion a ejecutar/realizar
    }
});

$("form").submit(function () {
    // aqui codigo/accion a ejecutar/realizar
    });
});
```

No se si me explique de manera correcta pero en resumen quiero que se ejecute una acción (de Javascript) SOLO cuando al darle al botón submit guarde en la base de datos, pero actualmente en lo que eh hecho, la acción se ejecuta cuando le doy al submit este o no este guardando en la base de datos.
Espero haberme explicado con claridad. De antemano ¡Gracias!...

EDIT: Si alguien pudiera darme un ejemplo de como lo haría, lo agradecería muchísimo <3

Comment: Cuando envías un formulario con la función `submit()`, los campos del formulario se envían al servidor y la página se actualiza; los datos se manejan en el lado del servidor. Es decir, la función submit() en realidad no devuelve nada, solo envía los datos del formulario al servidor. Si realmente deseas obtener la respuesta en Javascript (sin que se actualice la página), entonces deberás usar AJAX.

Comment: Lo supuse, pero no tengo "mucho conocimiento" sobre Ajax T-T De hecho no me importaría si se recarga la pagina, después de todo, al retornar el formulario con los errores de validación básicamente se recarga. Y ¡muchas gracias por responder @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Claro... A lo que iba, es a que para "que se ejecute una acción (de Javascript) SOLO cuando al darle al botón submit guarde en la base de datos", tendrías que capturar la respuesta del servidor en la misma página desde donde envías la solicitud con los datos del formulario (sin que se recargue), y eso es lo que te permitirá hacer si usas ajax.

Comment: Hasta ahora eres el único que me ah respondido... Me pondré en marcha a investigar e informarme sobre AJAX. Nuevamente, ¡¡Muchas gracias!! @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya resolví mi dilema, aqui un codigo de ejemplo de mi solución por si acaso, es como que la solicitud Ajax ejecuta sobre si misma en vez de buscar los datos en otro lugar...

```
$("#idDelFormulario").bind("submit", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr("method"),
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: $(this).serialize(),

        success: function (data) {
            //aqui codigo/accion a ejecutar/realizar
        },
    });
});
```

El ejemplo completo del que me adapte:

```
$("#formulario").bind("submit",function(){
        // Capturamnos el boton de envío
        var btnEnviar = $("#btnEnviar");
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr("method"),
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                /*
                * Esta función se ejecuta durante el envió de la petición al
                * servidor.
                * */
                // btnEnviar.text("Enviando"); Para button 
                btnEnviar.val("Enviando"); // Para input de tipo button
                btnEnviar.attr("disabled","disabled");
            },
            complete:function(data){
                /*
                * Se ejecuta al termino de la petición
                * */
                btnEnviar.val("Enviar formulario");
                btnEnviar.removeAttr("disabled");
            },
            success: function(data){
                /*
                * Se ejecuta cuando termina la petición y esta ha sido
                * correcta
                * */
                $(".respuesta").html(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                /*
                * Se ejecuta si la peticón ha sido erronea
                * */
                alert("Problemas al tratar de enviar el formulario");
            }
        });
        // Nos permite cancelar el envio del formulario
        return false;
    });
```

Y la fuente: https://formandocodigo.com/post/envio-de-formulario-por-ajax